# Use manifest.json in controllers and views (sapui5)

Tags: javascript, view, controller, manifest, sapui5

Is it possible to use some config parameters from the manifest.json in a view or controller within sapui5?

E.g. in my Component.js I can write smth like:

```
console.log(this.getMetadata().getManifestEntry("sap.app"));
```

I would like to access the *ManifestEntry* from my detail view (*JS*) because I specified the name of my model in the manifest. Until now I call my model in the view directly with:

```
this.getModel("dummyModel")
```

But I believe it would be better to call it indirectly so I don't have to change the string everywhere in case I wanna change the model name. E.g:

```
this.getModel(PLEASEHELP.getManifestEntry("sap.app").myModel);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the component from a controller via [getOwnerComponent()](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html#getOwnerComponent):

`this.getOwnerComponent().getManifestEntry("sap.app").myModel`